# LARAVEL: Carregar views sem refresh a partir de um menu fixo

Tags: laravel

Qual a melhor forma para implementar um sistema no laravel, onde ao clicar em um menu as views sejam carregadas sem refresh da página, apenas atualize o conteúdo do "content". Como posso implementar isso da maneira correta no laravel? Pois preciso carregar diferentes tabelas sem refresh e preenche-las com ajax, mas não sei se posso usar o controller para abrir as views ou uso jquery ajax para isso.

Comment: Se pode utilizar Ajax com Controller e Views sem problemas. Maneira correta é complicado dizer, se tem algum exemplo minimo que possamos ver?

Comment: Não tenho, tenho apenas o layout. Como posso chamar o Controller ao clicar no menu e sem atualizar a página?

Answer (score 1):

A melhor maneira de fazer isso é trabalhando com um framework reativo que te possibilita trabalhar no seu front como uma SPA (Single Page Application).

O laravel já vem com o vue.js como sendo o framework "embarcado" para esta tarefa.

O que você vai precisar fazer é configurar sua aplicação para usar uma rota web como sendo o entry-point da sua SPA e depois trabalhar na aplicação front end como sendo uma aplicação vue.js.

Dessa maneira, você consegue usar o vue-router para rotear as views, que serão componentes carregados em uma parte específica da sua página, fazendo com que você ganhe muita flexibilidade na geração de conteúdo.

Se você não conhece nada sobre SPA, eu sugiro procurar bons artigos na web (geralmente em inglês).

Espero ter ajudado.

PS: já usei muito jQuery ao longo da minha vida, hoje eu fujo, ainda mais depois do advento do ES5, 6 e 7.

Abraços.